# Show that the iterative method is of at least order 3

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

Show that the iterative method
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}-\frac{f''(x_n)}{2f'(x_n)}\bigg(\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\bigg)^2$$

with $x_0$ given, used to approximate $s$ such that $f(s) = 0$, is of at least order $3$, provided
that $f'(s) \neq 0$ where $s$ is a root.

Im really unsure how to answer this question so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html

Comment: Taylor expansion. The answer to basically every question in numerics.

Comment: This is also known as [Euler-Tshebyshev method](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Tschebyschow-Verfahren) and is related to the Halley and Laguerre methods

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=-f'(x)^{-1}f(x)$ be the Newton update and compute the Taylor series of a shifted argument with unknown quadratic factor (using $O(h^k)=O(f(x)^k)$)
\begin{align}
f(x+h+ah^2)&=f(x)+f'(x)(h+ah^2)+\frac12f''(x)(h+ah^2)^2+O(h^3)
\\
&=[f(x)+f'(x)h]+(af'(x)+\frac12f''(x))h^2+O(f(x)^3)
\end{align}
Now the first term vanishes by the definition of $h$ as Newton step, and the second is zero if $a=-\frac12f'(x)^{-1}f''(x)$, so that only third and higher order terms remain. This is the core for a proof of third order convergence.